# expected to be running in 'proxyzone' but it was not found in angular project

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

When create a new project ng test is working fine, after that I added Primeng and Bootstrap Libraries, now I am getting the error "expected to be running in 'proxyzone' but it was not found" I am not using "fakeAsync". code is attached.

```html
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing'
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(should have as title 'UI-design', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('UI-design');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span')?.textContent).toContain('UI-design app is running!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was resolved by setting the `compilerOptions.target` to `es2016` in my tsconfig.